# Cocoa - UIButton fade transition between UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled background image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uibutton

i created a UIButton subclass implementing additional features i need in my application.

I set two different background images for the states UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled.

When i set my button enable or disable, i want it to have a fade animation between the UIControlStateNormal image and the UIControlStateDisabled image.

How can i do that in my UIButton subclass ?

Answer (score 0):

UIButton does a lot for you automatically, if you want to add custom behavior it might be very hard to end up having the kind of animation you are looking for.

I would do it myself using a UIControl (UIButton superclass) and change the background images using the CALayer implicit(or explicit) [animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514).